# human sight at 1000x while looking into the mirror

Tags: brain, neurophysiology, human-physiology

I noticed that my eyeballs have the ability to see in what appears to be 1000x.
Setting the conditions: Look into a mirror while in a well lit room. (for me the lighting in my living room as opposed to the bathroom was not as direct and offered a better focus)  Position your face with your nose touching the mirror. Look at the twinkle of light that reflects off your eyeball. Stay focused on that twinkle with both eyes. Now, pull your face away from the mirror in order to focus your vision.  Position that twinkle of light directly to the center of your eyeball.
At this point that twinkle of light starts to look like a patch of cells under a microscope.  My left and right eye are different images.  My question: Am I looking at the cellular array that makes up my retina?   Eric McBrearty

Comment: What color and shape is the image? Red equal spaced cells? A different visual effect at 1000x is If you look up into the blue sky long enough, and with enough attention, you should be able to see tiny blue-white dots flashing around the sky.The phenomenon was so well-known that it acquired the nickname "blue-sky sprites," and they're actually white blood cells moving through your eye.

Comment: Not sure why this is gathering close-votes as "personal medical question". This is a common phenomenon that many people have noticed and has a non-personal  answer to it. com.prehensible alludes to a similar phenomenon in his comment above. I vote to keep open, and I hope someone takes the time to write a good answer here :)